# Getting an error wile trying to open a TCP socket - c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tcp

[image]

I'm trying to build a block that acts as server and client to send and receive data (2 duplicate versions in 2 different computers) through a TCP connection.

This is what I did and I'm trying to test using the windows commandd line "netstat -ab" to try to find the tcp connection but I can't find it.

Apart from the given error, what am i doing wrong?

```
bool IPTunnel::runBlock(void) {
    int ready =
        inputSignals[0]->ready(); // int ready2 = inputTCPConnetion[0]->ready();

    // server
    SOCKET sockfd, newsockfd;
    int portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    SOCKET n;

    // create a socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0) printf("\n ERROR opening socket");


    // bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    portno = 5500;


    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    char ipad[10] = "127.0.0.1";
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *ipad; // INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);



    // if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    auto sd = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    // if (sd < 0)
    //  printf("\n ERROR on binding");


    listen(sockfd, 5);

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);
    if(newsockfd < 0) printf("ERROR on accept");

    printf("server: got connection from %s port %d\n",
           inet_ntop(serv_addr.sin_family, &ipad, buffer, clilen),
           ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));

    send(newsockfd, "Hello, world!\n", 13, 0);

    // bzero(buffer, 256);

    n = _read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
    if(n < 0) printf("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);
    while(true) {
    }
    // close(newsockfd);
    // close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error that gives: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE5031B7EC (ucrtbased.dll) in ip_tunnel.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

in the _read function...

Comment: Having the quite lenghty manual pages pasted into the question pretty much disqualifies the minimalistic part of it. Noone qualified to answer your question would have problems finding info about how `socket`s works.

Comment: https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/04/08/socket-programming-in-c-version-1/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this line is definitely wrong:

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *ipad; //INADDR_ANY;
```

If you want to receive incoming TCP connections on the loopback device, you should do something more like this:

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_aton("127.0.0.1");
```

(or if you want them to be received from any connected network device, specify INADDR_ANY instead)

Also, make sure you called `WSAStartup()` at the beginning of your program, Windows sockets won't work correctly if you haven't done that.

One last nitpick:

```
while(true){}
```

is not a good way to pause execution of your program.  For one thing, it will typically spin a CPU at 100% usage, which is very inefficient, and for another, it invokes undefined behavior according to the C++ standard.

A better way to do get that behavior would be something like:

```
while(true) {Sleep(1000);}
```

Also this part is wrong/weird:

```
SOCKET n;
[...]
n = _read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
```

... in that `_read` doesn't return a `SOCKET`, it returns an `int`.  I think you meant to declare `int n;` instead.

One last potential problem:  if your call to `bzero(buffer, 256);` is commented out, then it's quite possible for `buffer` to contain no zero-bytes after the `_read()` call returns, in which case your `printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);` call afterwards could read right past the end of the `buffer` array and out into the wild blue yonder of other memory, potentially causing a crash (or at least causing a lot of garbage bytes to be printed).  The fix is to make sure the `buffer` array contains a 0/NUL byte at the end of the valid bytes that were placed there by the `_read()` call.

Comment: It's common for an error an earlier location in the code to result in a crash at some later point of the code's execution.  It's also not unheard for the debugger to misidentify the location of a crash (e.g. if the stack has been corrupted, or if the C++ optimizer out-clevered
 the debugger)

Comment: I uncommented the bzero function and I still receive an error everytime I call the _read function